# Reading object from file throws IllegalAccessException

Tags: android, file, exception, layout, serialization

I know that I shouldn't use this approach but for testing purposes I am.
I created a class that extends `LinearLayout` and implements `Serializable` to be able to save the whole layout to a file.

After adding views to this layout I'm writting it successfully to a file. But when reading back the object I get an error `IllegalAcessException`; Is there any way to solve this issue?

**CustomLayout.class**

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout implements Serializable{

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1000;

public LinearLayout_Serializable(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public LinearLayout_Serializable(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset){
    super(context,attributeset);
}

}
```

Any help please? and thanks in advance

**Full error**

```
 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887): java.io.InvalidClassException:  android.widget.LinearLayout; IllegalAccessException

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.resolveConstructorClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:692)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:653)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at com.example.fastlayout.MainActivity.readFromFile(MainActivity.java:232)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at com.example.fastlayout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)

 02-23 12:06:01.165: W/System.err(21887):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)

 02-23 12:06:01.170: W/System.err(21887):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your full stack trace.

Comment: I edited my question to post it :) @FD_

Answer (score 3):

Seems like he [ObjectStreamClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html) is looking for an empty constructor to instantiate your custom class.

```
 // Has to have an empty constructor
        if (constructor == null) {
            String className = constructorClass != null ? constructorClass.getName() : null;
            throw new InvalidClassException(className, "IllegalAccessException");
        }
```

[LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) does not have an empty constructor. Try just adding an empty constructor

```
public LinearLayout_Serializable() {
    this(//getContextSomehow());
}
```

Comment: I tried declaring a static variable for the context to save its instance and I did an empty constructor with super(//the saved context) in it but it didn't work. Is this what you suggested? @Nelson Ramirez

Comment: Yeah, having a context to pass into the next constructor will be tricky from reflection.

Comment: Turns out that LinearLayout needs an implicite constructor to initialize it which I don't know how to work around it

Comment: I guess you'd want to try to get a class ref yourself and instantiate it yourself..